# Nginx pagespeed module increases page size with no filters?

Tags: nginx, pagespeed

I am trying to use pagespeed with latest Nginx build (1.15.2), although as it turns out when I enable pagespeed the pagesize increases significantly to 32kb from 9kb with no filters:

**nginx.conf**

```
pagespeed on;
pagespeed RewriteLevel PassThrough;
pagespeed FileCachePath /var/ngx_pagespeed_cache;
```

Results with pagespeed **enabled**: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifCEz.png

Results with pagespeed **disabled**: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RGRH.png

I disable cache in both tests and each time I get identical results, why is this happening?

Comment: To mark a question as solved, you can tick/check the answer you prefer below, when the system lets you.

Answer (score 0):

jmarantz pointed out that gzip might be the reason and he was completely right, I compared the content of the index.php but both were identical, however I accidentally left gzip variables in my nginx.conf with `gzip off;`, pagespeed decided to still use gzip even though I declared it as off.

Thanks works good now.